# jQuery $.post() and full URL's

Tags: php, firefox, jquery, safari, google-chrome

I am working on a site and have 3 different branches. Typical dev->stage->production situation.

All 3 run on 3 different urls:

> prod: http://www.domain.com
>
> stage: http://www.domain.com/stage
>
> dev: http://www.domain.com/dev

So i am trying to have universal code that runs on all 3 without any modification to file paths.

To achieve that i just have `base_path` var set, to whatever CodeIgniter installation is configured with for this particular branch.

```
var base_url = "<?=base_url();?>"; // This sets base_url accordingly.

$.post(base_url + 'login/ajaxLogin', { // See note below
       login_email: $('#login_email').val(),
       login_pass: $('#login_pass').val(),
       },
       function(data) {
          if(data == 'true') {
             window.location.href = base_url;
          } else {
             $('h2').replaceWith('<h2 style="color:#b81900;">Login Failed</h2>');
             return false;
          }
});
```

Above code works fine in Chrome. But it does not work in Safari and Firefox.
In Firefox it fails silently, and in Safari I get `"Unable to load resource: cancelled"`

**NOTE**: If i remove `base_url` and just set script path to `/login/ajaxLogin`, `/dev/login/ajaxLogin` or `/stage/login/ajaxLogin` everything works perfectly.

It appears that I may be hitting Cross-domain scripting restriction, but I am not sure why?

Yes, I am familiar with [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and yes, I have seen this on jQuery's site:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin
>   policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a **different** domain, subdomain,
>   or protocol.
>
> If a request with `jQuery.post()` returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the
>   script has also called the global `.ajaxError()` method.

None of the above applies in my case as I am staying within my domain, so I am not entirely sure what is going on, but i would really like to find a workaround for this issue.

Comment: I'm gonna ask the first stupid question, but is the base_path function returning the same path in all instances?

Comment: It might be worth, firstly, looking up what Javascript this PHP actually produces, and, secondly, using the Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug to look up the URL of the request that fails.

Comment: `base_url()` adds a trailing slash to the url, so you may be ending up with something like `http://url.com//stage/login/ajaxLogin` which might be throwing things off. As @Matchu said, check to see what URL's are being produced.

Comment: @jerebear: yep, i am sure it does. i log to the console and it looks ok.
@Matchu: yes, i used dev tools and firebug. Also looked at the server logs. Everything appears the same, except that Firefox does `OPTIONS` request instead of `POST`
@stormdrain: yep. i know, thats why i have `base_url + 'login/ajaxLogin'` to compensate for trailing slash

Comment: Looks like you're setting a variable called "base_path" then using "base_url"?

Comment: @Brenton, oops. thats only in this post. that was the only line i did not cut/paste. it looks right in my code... ill fix the posts

Comment: So... I'm getting confused now. The requests that you expect end up getting sent? Do you get the response you expect, as well?

Comment: @Matchu: in Chrome i do. it works. in Firefox i only see `OPTIONS` request sent, but no `POST`, so it just fails. In Safari I do see `POST`, but it throws `Unable to load resource: cancelled` immediately after that. PHP script does `echo true/false`, and everything works if i get rid of complete URL and just use URI.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but unless that function wraps the value in quotes, you'll need to wrap it yourself.

```
var base_path = "<?= base_path(); ?>";
```

Comment: Good call.  Didn't even catch that it's a string.  That may be the issue!

Comment: my apologies, I already have it in quotes, i just did not copy/paste it. `var base_url = "<?=base_url();?>";`